# How to show whether there's a significant higher rate?

Tags: r, statistical-significance, excel

Maybe someone can help me or at least give me some clues.

I have 1057 patients all with different types of prostheses. 
One of them seems to have a higher revision rate than the others.

```
total numbers:
prosthesisA 662
prosthesisB 162
prosthesisC 151
other       82

revision rate:
prosthesisA 9   1,36%
prosthesisB 11  6,79%
prosthesisC 3   1,99%
other       4   4,88%
```

Could anyone tell me how I can show whether the revision rate of prothesisB (6,79%) is significantly higher or not compared to the other prostheses (incl. "other")?

Thank you & kind regards

Edit:
Is it possible to compare only the prosthesisB with all others at once?
I've created the following contingency table:

```
        prostB  other   total
Rev     11      16      27
noRev   162     868     1030
        173     884     1057

Odds-Ratio = (11*868)/(16*162) = 3.68
p-Value (Fisher Test) = 0.001
```

Can I say now that the chances for a revision with prosthesisB are ~3.5 times higher compared to all others? 
Is this plausible since the p-Value of the Fisher's exact test is highly significant?

Comment: When you say "compared to the others", do you mean "compared to prosthesisA, prosthesisC and other", or "compared to other"?

Comment: Yeah, sorry. I should have stated it clearer. I mean compared to all other prosthesis including "other".

Answer (score 1):

You should be careful about formulating your hypotheses after seeing the data.  Instead of this, what I would do is a logistic regression with the IV being body part.

Comment: I can probably only perform the logistic regression if I have the raw data, correct?

Comment: I've added an own approach to the original answer. Do you think it's correct? Thank you!

Comment: Yes, you need the raw data to do the logistic.

Your approach does what I said to be careful about.  You can DO it, but it's a bit of fishing, and the resultant p-values are not correct.

Comment: Thank you Peter! I think my solution should do it for now.